# How do I create a Table from the common attributes of other Tables

Tags: mysql, database, join

I have the following scenario

Table A has x,y,z columns
Table B has a,b,x,y columns
Table C has a,s,x,y columns

Now I want to create a new Table with the common columns of A,B,C. That is the new Table will be having x,y columns with all the rows from three tables. How do I do that?

I have come up with this query
`create table tablename as select A.x,A.y,A.z from A,B,C where (A.x=B.x and A.x=C.x) and (A.y=B.y and A.y=C.y)and (A.z=B.z and A.z=C.z)`

Since I am trying to query on Un existing columns. It's giving me columns does not exist error. 
`

Comment: You are not explaining (in your question and comments) what you want! There are lots of ways to combine tables. Explain which one you want. Explain how the output is formed from the input. Give example input and output.  *Why* are you asking for this? Can you quote an assignment? If you want all combinations of rows then you *must* output multiple x, y and z columns (renamed)! If you want just one copy of each column, and the input columns are different, *what is the output column supposed to be*? If you just want all rows that match on x, y and z that's the JOIN on equalities.

Comment: What are "the common columns of A,B,C"? x and y? a, x and y? Do you mean *all* the columns: x, y, z, a, b, s? Do you mean A.x, A.y, A.z, B.a, B.b, B.x, B.y, C.a, C.s, C.x and C.y?

Answer (score 0):

Try joining all the three tables together like:

```
SELECT a.x, a.y, a.z, b.a, b.b, c.a, c.s
FROM A a LEFT JOIN B b
ON   a.x = b.x AND a.y = b.y
RIGHT JOIN C c
ON   a.x = c.x AND a.y = c.y
```

Comment: Sir, it's returning an empty result

Comment: Are you sure? Paste your sample data.

Comment: Sir, it might be correct. But just see the edited question.I need all the rows from three tables

Comment: what do you mean by all the result?

Comment: Even though the data in the columns is different, I should get those rows. Only constraint is I should be having common column names

Comment: No its not the case. I think then you are looking for Left join rather. See my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

if you want the common columns and data then you have to join them:
the `x` and `y` are common between all three tables then you can create it like below:

```
Create TABLE Table_name
as
SELECT a.x, a.y
FROM A a INNER JOIN B b
ON   a.x = b.x AND a.y = b.y
INNER JOIN C
ON   a.x = c.x AND a.y = c.y
```

you may want common columns but not all data to be common maybe data from table A and other common data then you can use LEFT or RIGHT of FULL OUTER JOINS

Comment: You may be correct but I have edited the question. I need all the rows from all the Tables. I mean to say that data need to be common.

Comment: Ok, the the query should do what you wanted, if no then for sure you have not common data in three tables (x and y)

Comment: The thing is even if I don't have common data .. I should be able to get those rows

Comment: you say "I want data even if the data is not exists" it's a little none logic and confused, you can `UNION` the select with `select null,null` or something else, to be sure you have some result

Answer (score 0):

> Table A has x,y,z columns
>   Table B has a,b,x,y columns
>   Table C has a,s,x,y columns

- Maybe you want all rows that can be made by matching rows from A, B and C, with one copy of each matched/shared column:

  ```
  select A.x, A.y, A.z, B.a, B.b, C.s
  from A
  join B on A.x = B.x and A.y = B.y
  join C on B.a = C.a and B.x = C.x and B.y = C.y
  ```

  which is:

  ```
  select * from  A natural join B natural join C
  ```
- Maybe you want all rows that can be made from A, B and C:

  ```
  select A.x as Ax, A.y as Ay, A.z as z,
      B.a as Ba, B.b as Bb, B.x as Bx, B.y as By,
      C.a as Ca, C.s as Cs, C.x as Cx, C.y as Cy
  from A cross join B cross join C
  ```
- The natural full outer join of two tables returns all the rows in their natural join (ie those that can be made from matching rows while keeping only one copy of each column) plus the rows you get by taking an unmatched row and adding columns that only appear in the other table, set to null. It is the union of the natural left join and the natural right join of the tables. If you had two tables maybe that's what you would want. But for three tables,

  ```
  (A natural full outer join B) natural full outer join C
  ```

  is not the same as:

  ```
  A natural full outer join (B natural full outer join C)
  ```

  So there is no:

  ```
  A natural full outer join B natural full outer join C
  ```
- Maybe you mean the rows you get by taking a row from A, B or C and adding  columns that only appear in other tables, set to null:

  ```
        select x, y, z, null as a, null as b, null as s from A
  union select x, y, null as z, a, b, null as s from B
  union select x, y, null as z, a, null as b, s from C
  ```
- Maybe you mean that but selecting only x and y (columns common to all tables) or x, y and a (columns common to two or more tables.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this query :

```
select a.x, a.y, a.z, b.a, b.b, c.a, c.s from A a, B b, C c where a.x = b.x AND a.y = b.y
AND a.x = c.x AND a.y = c.y
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it - how will this create a table?